# Nginx Load Balance with proxy_ pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, nginx-upstreams

I am working on nginx proxy pass with load balancer and the problem is that I have 2 different url for both the backend server, let say my domain is xyzzy.com and 1 request out of 10 should go to xyz-1.com/123/xyz/andsoon and another 9 request should go to xyz-2.com/456/456/andsoon

how to achieve this using nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide **weight** to your upstream servers:

```
upstream myapp1 {
        server  xyz-2.com/456/456/andsoon weight=9;
        server  xyz-1.com/123/xyz/andsoon;
    }
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_weighted_load_balancing

Comment: Using an URI prefix additionally to the server address or domain name is not allowed inside the `upstream` block. With this configuration nginx will throw an error like `nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "xyz-2.com/456/456/andsoon" in ...`

Comment: @IvanShatsky You're right